# Filtering on a Window function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, window-functions

I have the following model:

```
class Foobar(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()
```

And I figured out how to calculate the delta of consecutive `foo` fields by using window functions:

```
qs = Foobar.objects.annotate(
    delta=F('foo') - Window(
        Lag('foo'),
        partition_by=F('variant'),
        order_by=F('timestamp').asc(),
    )
)
```

Now I only want the records from this where `delta` is negative:

```
qs.filter(delta__lte=0)
```

But as you might expect, this gives an error:

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.
```

How can I do this filtering with the Django ORM?

Comment: This is known issue as of the moment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333

Comment: As for other options, raw sql?

Comment: @bdbd This is one piece in a larger query that I'm trying to build. Ideally I do it all with the ORM rather than raw SQL. I found [this article](https://blog.oyam.dev/django-filter-by-window-function/) which shows how to embed the query from a query set as a subquery to filter on it. Then I also found `Subquery()` in the Django API. But I have not yet figured out how to use it instead of a raw SQL string as shown in the blog article.

Comment: [This comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333#comment:20) on @BrianDestura's post might be useful (TLDR: use a `RawQuerySet` to wrap your subquery with a condition)

Answer (score 8):

Django 4.2 supports filtering on WINDOW expressions.
See the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.2/#models) and also [the pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/15922).

Comment: Thanks for the information! This is an old question and I've moved on from the project that originally prompted me to ask. I don't even do Django currently.